# How to specify Content-Type of all responses once in API Blueprint?

Tags: apiblueprint, dredd

In order to satisfy Dredd, I have to write this for every response in my API Blueprint document:

```
+ Response 201 (application/json; charset=utf-8)
```

Is there a way to specify the media type (`(application/json; charset=utf-8)`) once, globally, for every response? This would have cleaned the document a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not a supported scenario. I suggest you to file an issue on API Blueprint repository on GitHub to eventually get this feature request evaluated!